# Splash screen does not hide

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-splash-screen

I followed the instructions for this blog for iOS: [Building a splash screen in React Native](https://blog.logrocket.com/splash-screen-react-native/)

I was able to get the app built and the splash screen is displayed when open. However, the splash screen never disappears.

Here's the `App.tsx` file:

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'; //import useEffect();
import SplashScreen from "react-native-splash-screen";

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

function Section({children, title}: SectionProps): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide(); //hides the splash screen on app load.
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.tsx</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="Bye world!">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

As far as I can tell, I've imported the necessary libraries and added in the `useEffect` function call the way the tutorial explained it. Not sure how to begin to troubleshoot this.

And here is the AppDelegate.mm file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"AwesomeProject2";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  [RNSplashScreen show]; 
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

/// This method controls whether the `concurrentRoot`feature of React18 is turned on or off.
///
/// @see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html
/// @note: This requires to be rendering on Fabric (i.e. on the New Architecture).
/// @return: `true` if the `concurrentRoot` feature is enabled. Otherwise, it returns `false`.
- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  return true;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 10):

**June 23rd 2023 Solution** - React Native "0.72.0" splash screen not hiding AppDelegate.mm

After scraping the "web 2" for a solution, I got it to work using the following...

`App.tsx` file - import and `useEffect`:

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

useEffect(() => {
    const ac = new AbortController();

    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }, 1000); <<<==== SET YOUR PREFERRED TIMEOUT!

    return function cleanup() {
      ac.abort();
    };
}, []);
```

`AppDelegate.mm` file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"Closer"; <<<==== CHANGE TO YOUR PROJECT NAME!
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  
  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

*That's all folks!*

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.

Mentioned here: (https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/71#issuecomment-1743383657)

```
[RNSplashScreen show];  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

to

```
BOOL ret = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]; if (ret == YES) { [RNSplashScreen show];  } return ret;
```

I encountered this issue with:
"react-native": "0.72.4"
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0"

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact problem, and it seems like we're not alone ([Source 1](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/574), [Source 2](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/512)). It appears that the library is no longer maintained ([Source 3](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/533), [Source 4](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/554)).

Consider switching to [`react-native-bootsplash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash). It has worked perfectly for me. It appears to be the new standard.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem.
Calling `[RNSplashScreen show];` right before the `return YES;` which is the solution for some also does not solve this.

Even hiding the splash screen explicitly like this

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
   [RNSplashScreen hide];
}
```

does not hide the splash screen. This appeared for me all of a sudden after upgrading react-native and it seems to be a problem for many, as Daniels proposes I think [bootsplash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your AppDelegate.mm

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"GrandPrixInfo";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  bool didFinish=[super application:application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  [RNSplashScreen show];   
  return didFinish;        
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).